# Position Of Script Tags In HTML Document - <head> & <body> Has Different Behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I've got this piece of HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Backbone.js Demos</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

<script type="x-tmpl" id="list_tmpl">
    <span><%= part1 %><%= part2 %></span>
    <a href="#swappy" class='swap'>[SWAP]</a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#del" class='remove'>[DELETE]</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When the script tags are between the `body` tags, my scripts work properly.  However, if I move all of my script tags to the `head`, they cease working.  I'm baffled as to why.  Is there any reason for this behaviour? Thank you all for your time and help!

**EDIT: APP**

```
(function($){

    Backbone.sync = function (method, model, success, error){
        success();
    };

    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            part1: 'Hello',
            part2: 'World'
        }
    });

    var ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Item
    });

    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',

        events: {
            'click .swap': 'swap',
            'click .remove': 'remove'
        },

        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'swap', 'remove');

            this.model.bind('change', this.render);
            this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
        },

        render: function(){
            $(this.el).html(_.template($('#list_tmpl').html(), this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        unrender: function(){
            $(this.el).remove();
        },

        swap: function(){
            var swapped = {
                part1: this.model.get('part2'),
                part2: this.model.get('part1')
            };

            this.model.set(swapped);
        },

        remove: function(){
            this.model.destroy();
        }
    });

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('body'),

        events: {
            'click #add': 'addItem'
        },

        initialize: function (){
            this.counter = 0;

            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem', 'appendItem');

            this.collection = new ItemList();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);

            this.render();
        },

        render: function(){
            $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add Item</button>");
            $(this.el).append("<ul id='todoList'/>");
        },

        addItem: function(){
            this.counter++;
            var item = new Item();
            item.set({
                part2: item.get('part2') + this.counter
            });

            this.collection.add(item);
        },

        appendItem: function(item){
            var itemView = new ItemView({
                model: item
            });

            $('#todoList', this.el).append(itemView.render().el);
        }
    });

    var Tasker = new AppView();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: First remove all `https:` and `http:` in your `<script src>` like so: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` since you are currently mixing https and http. Second, add the `app.js` code to your question since I believe in there lies your problem.

Comment: Can u post app.js so that we can check it out

Comment: Your app.js executes immediately and does not wait until the DOM is ready, and since javascript normally works on elements that are available you'll need to place the script below the elements themselves to make sure they are available to the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior happens when the js file uses the body once it's loaded, so they must be embedded within body.

you can put jquery,json and underscore files in the head.

Other files, you must check if they don't call the body when they are loaded.

Comment: they do indeed. The app.js which is my backbone app has the el attribute as body.  So that's probably why.  You're spot on.  However, one more question.  Why must they be embedded in the body when they use it?

Comment: all js files within the head tag are loaded before the body is loaded, so the document.body will be undefined. you have two options:1- put them within the body, 2- put them within the head but don't start any function unless the body is loaded using $(document).ready(function(){})

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to fix this is to start your app.js with

```
$(function() {
```

instead of

```
(function($){
```

than jQuery executes the script after the DOM is available. Than you can leave your scripts in the head.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add app.js at the End of the Body as it is using the attributes of the elements in the page.

**Use this Markup. Always close Script Tags.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Backbone.js Demos</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="x-tmpl" id="list_tmpl">
    <span><%= part1 %><%= part2 %></span>
    <a href="#swappy" class='swap'>[SWAP]</a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#del" class='remove'>[DELETE]</a>
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```